# Laravel redirects at forms with ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

My application is built with October CMS that implements Laravel at all.

When i use `Redirect::to` on link/button with ajax requests, the server runs the redirect normally.

But ever when returns `Redirect::to` at submitted forms with ajax requests the redirect not works.

Can someone explain to me why this occurs?

Comment: the problem is because all the time i need to return one location to make the redirect at front-end

Comment: PHP-level redirects are not respected by Ajax on the JavaScript side. You'll need to have JavaScript rewrite the window location as part of the success callback of your Ajax call.